# Is it true that the gcd of cubes is the cube of gcd?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Is it true that $\forall a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$, $\gcd(a^3, b^3)=\gcd(a,b)^3$? I cannot find a counterexample, nor have I been able to finish a proof. One thing I tried was:

$\gcd(a^3, b^3)= \gcd(a^3, b^3-a^3)=\gcd(a^3, (b-a)(b^2+ba+a^2))$ but I don't see how this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a=gcd(a,b)j$

$b=gcd(a,b)k$

with $gcd(j,k)=1$

$a^3=gcd(a,b)^3j^3$

$b^3=gcd(a,b)^3k^3$

$gcd(j^3, k^3)=1$

Can you see it now?

Comment: In the last line, $\gcd$ of what?

Comment: @user1227849937 edited now...

Comment: @user1227849937 It uses the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, as most proofs in number theory do...